# Joomla 2.5 delete from database won't work

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm creating a function for my component which should delete a row from the database based on params in the where, but it doesn't delete the line.
If I'm executing the query in phpMyAdmin it works perfectly so I don't get why it doesn't work in my component.

here is my function:

```
function deleteItem($itemID, $userID){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    //$conditions = array($db->quoteName('user_id').'='.$userID, $db->quoteName('itemid').'='.$itemID);
    //$query->delete($db->quoteName('#__mycomponent'));
    //$query->where($conditions);
    $query = 'DELETE FROM `#__mycomponent` WHERE `user_id`='.$userID.' AND `itemid`='.$itemID;
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $db->query();

    $msg = 'DELETED';

    return $msg;  
}
```

As you see I tried the Joomla Docs way and as a normal query but none of them worked.
What am I missing?

Comment: if you use `var_dump($userID);` and `var_dump($itemID);` do you get the result `null` for each one?

Comment: I did not var_dump them but I'm triggering the function with jQuery and the function returns the deleted text so I think both of the params are passed correctly. But if I trying to echo error with try/exceptions the $msg also returns deleted. so I'm thinking somehow mysql doesn't find a match for my where, but don't know why.

Comment: Try using an actual number that matches the userID in the database. Use the query that you current have commented out as that is how it should be written for Joomla 2.5+

Comment: put
echo $query->dump();  to get the generated query.  Also try using the joomla JDatabaseQuery api so you can test parts better and get the quoting right. Both of those are integers, is that right?